# How to give an instructions to all turtles based on a value of a single turtle

Tags: netlogo

I want to do something like this.

```
ask turtle 0 [if <some turtle 0 property> [ask turtles [ <do something> ]]
```

But `turtle 0` can't ask all turtles. It can't ask `observer` either.

A workaround is to create a local variable `property-true?`

```
let property-true? false
ask turtle 0 [set property-true? <some turtle 0 property>]
if property-true? [ask turtles [ <do something> ]]
```

There must be a better way, but I haven't been able to think of it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten about `of`.

```
if [the-property?] of turtle 0 [ask turtles [ <do something> ]]
```

My mistake was thinking that there was no way to determine the value of `the-property?` without `ask turtle 0`.  But `of` lets me do it.